# Have asp.net base page property show up in @Page attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, intellisense, attributes

I have create a list of public properties in our custom page.  However, when I want to assign the property on any aspx file, it does not show in intellisense and when I use it it said it is a invalid attribute of element "Page".

So, 2 question.

1. How do I make it such that it shows up in intellisense?
2. Can I set any localize variable as a value of the property in the page directive?

Thanks!

here is the property on my base page:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Robot meta tag
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Robots
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I know that it will still work if I assigned it, but it'll be nice to have intellisense of our UI developers.  The more important question is if I can set a localized value on the property within the page directive attribute.

Comment: Can you show an example of a property declaration in the custom base page, how you attempt to use it?

Comment: Show us the code.  Did you really call your class "Page" and not something like HermansCustomPage?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't control intellisense.  It should show up, but rarely does if ever, at least for me.
2. You cannot set page class properties in the @Page directive that I'm aware of, and if you can, you can't control intellisense in that either.

You should be able to use public properties or methods in the page, even though they don't show up...  Could you post some sample code so we can see what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these statements are true!  You definitely *can* control intellisense, it just requires a Visual Studio plug in to do, so not very practical here.  You can also set custom Page properties in the @Page directive.

Comment: You mean develop a custom plugin?  That's not the intent of the question, unless @Herman corrects me.  But personally what I meant is that intellisense sucks at times and I don't get custom properties to show up.  I never said it didn't ever, but that it didn't for me.  And #2 I said that I was aware of, thanks for letting me know.